# Making 3 by 3 buttons in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to learning how to use Android Studio. I was trying to follow a Youtube Video on how to create a game of TicTacToe and some part of the instruction was unclear.

At the moment, I have this:

[image]

But I want to be like this:

[image]

My `activity_main.xml` file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player 1 : 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:text="Player 2 : 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:text="reset" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My `MainActivity.java` file code:

```
package com.example.tictactoe;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

    private boolean player1Turn = true;

    private int rountCount;

    private int player1Points;
    private int player2Points;

    private TextView textViewplayer1;
    private TextView textViewplayer2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I feel that mostly something is not correct with the button section of the script of the `activity_main.xml` file.

**Which part of my code am I not doing correctly?**

Comment: usually on these tutorials there's a link to a github page or a reference to where you can download the code

Comment: Not for that video, here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPIim51-h8I&list=PLfkjmrXARY70YQqFDQJD54WRsc0FAVaDD&index=2

Comment: I thought I typed the same thing that he had, but came out differently.

Comment: it's fine, it's just a useful thing to know for future :)

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it wrong first don't make height of your parent layout to `match parent` and secondly you have to user nested `linear layouts` to achieve your goal I would suggest you to use `constraint layout` instead.

I have left the last row for you to complete, and I have sorted your code out so I am sure you won't find any issue doing that :)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player 1 : 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:text="Player 2 : 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:text="reset" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_00"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="60sp" />
            
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_11"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="60sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

      

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: i agree that constraint layout is a better solution, but because OP is just following a tutorial i'm sure they will reach that part (hopefully) eventually

Comment: @a_local_nobody yeah that's why I used linear layout and gave it as a suggestion :)

Comment: yeah this is the only answer that teaches OP something, because you left out the last row and have _suggested_ constraint layout, hence my upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Set heights of buttons to wrap_content instead of match_parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player 1 : 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:text="Player 2 : 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:text="reset" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. But not tested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player 1 : 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:text="Player 2 : 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:text="reset" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TableLayout` as following

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Player 1 : 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:text="Player 2 : 0"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:text="reset" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:textSize="60sp" />
            <Button
                android:textSize="60sp" />
            <Button
                android:textSize="60sp" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:textSize="60sp" />
            <Button
                android:textSize="60sp" />
            <Button
                android:textSize="60sp" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:textSize="60sp" />
            <Button
                android:textSize="60sp" />
            <Button
                android:textSize="60sp" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OP is following a tutorial and doesn't have any understanding of what a TableLayout is, i'm not sure your answer is valid, even if it works

Answer (score 0):

Depend your button id. I think it is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Player 1 : 0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
        android:text="Player 2 : 0"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:text="reset" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_00"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_02"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="60sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_11"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_12"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="60sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_22"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="60sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```